# A computer screen shows a 98 × 98 chessboard, colored in the usual way.

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, chessboard

This is a question from the 1998 math olympiad I found 2 solutions in the following places: [book1 pg.32](https://books.google.com/books?id=EnbWgFFHtr0C&pg=PA31&lpg=PA31&dq=a%20computer%20screen%20shows%20a%2098%20x%2098%20chessboard,%20colored%20in%20the%20usual&source=bl&ots=Z1-zL2AP8h&sig=B3ytYuyOBBXMazlqb_eDdlyMcXU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjUy42S-e7fAhXN31QKHSg0DjcQ6AEwCXoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=a%20computer%20screen%20shows%20a%2098%20x%2098%20chessboard%2C%20colored%20in%20the%20usual&f=false) [book2 pg.163](https://books.google.com/books?id=T0CnqnoKu6QC&pg=PA163&lpg=PA163&dq=a%20computer%20screen%20shows%20a%2098%20x%2098%20chessboard,%20colored%20in%20the%20usual&source=bl&ots=I5WBhsCiwF&sig=qnzDQpQFQbry3-DflxANnadfN40&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjUy42S-e7fAhXN31QKHSg0DjcQ6AEwCHoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=a%20computer%20screen%20shows%20a%2098%20x%2098%20chessboard%2C%20colored%20in%20the%20usual&f=false)
however, I was having trouble understanding them. Any help would be appreciated

There is a 98 × 98 chessboard, colored in the usual way. One
can select any rectangle with sides on the lines of the chessboard
and as a result, the colors in the selected rectangle switch
(black becomes white and white becomes black). What is the minimum number
of changes needed to make the chessboard all one color?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow [a few guidelines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, what have you tried so far, and just where are you stuck? This is not a homework-answering site: many of us want to see that you have put significant work into the problem.

Comment: Yes, even if that is just providing further details as to precisely what part of the textbook explanation you don't follow. I would assume Olympiad problems are not your homework, but a task you are working on for enrichment.